# Is it agile friendly to propose equal distribution of dev tasks at the beginning of the sprint?

Tags: agile, scrum, task-organization

My question is about Agile and if there is a known technics to split "equally" dev tasks between developers.

In a backlog, at the beginning of the sprint, our devteam is asked to take tasks from the backlog, imagine a team (5 developers) and there is always someone "faster" and takes all "easy" tasks and leaves hard ones for reste of the team, and it is not fair as at the end of every sprint, this developer looks more productive and shines more than everyone.

Is it agile friendly to say : we have 10 easy tasks, let's split them equally : 2 for each developer ?

Comment: Your problem is that you are using "how many tasks completed" as a metric. Stop doing that.

Comment: @PhilipKendall It's not "me" but the scrum master, the product owner and the client who just check the quantity at the end of every sprint, we (developers) know that the complexity is the real metric. But it's still creating a collective bad mood.

Comment: Perhaps you can assign a value to each task?

Comment: It sounds like your employer is just another example of a company that thinks that having sprints and a scrum master makes a company agile - **it doesn't**, and you can't make yourself "agile" by tweaks to your task assignment process.

Comment: @PhilipKendall is correct, this isn't a process problem. It's a management problem. Using the wrong measures and not knowing what and how to measure isn't solved by task distribution. It's a bit like trying to have a more "vegetarian friendly" meal by ensuring that everybody has equal access to drinks, rather than one person having them all.

Comment: To summarize, we shouldn't make fair distribution of tasks, but make everyone understand what are the correct metrics.

Comment: The only metric you should be worrying about is "Our highest priority is to satisfy the customer through early and continuous delivery of valuable software."

Comment: Sounds like a closed budget to me. The customer gives xK dollars/euros and it does expect n story points by that budget. Agile doesn't work that way.

Comment: @PhilipKendall: _"you are using "how many tasks completed" as a metric"_ Fully agree with not using the metric, but  even if the amount of tasks wasn't being used as a metric, the question remains the same for developers who cherry-pick the easy tasks or those with a known overestimation.

Comment: @Flater Agreed, but that's a different question from the one being asked here which is "is this agile?". Personally, I've never found it a problem - some developers are better used for the easy, turn the handle, tasks, some developers are better used for the hard tasks which need deeper thought and planning. That doesn't necessarily fit into a "scrum" framework where you try and pretend all your dev team members are perfectly interchangeable, but that's one of the reasons I'm not a huge fan of scrum.

Comment: @PhilipKendall: _"that's a different question from the one being asked here"_ The question specifically mentions someone taking _easy_ tasks and leaving _hard_ tasks for the others. You can argue that OP's question's phrasing has a mild case of 'XY problem' about it, but in this case the X is actually explained so it's not a _problem_ in that sense. Even in the answer you posted, you also first addressed the direct question (Y) but then predominantly stepped into discussing the underlying problem (X).

Comment: We used a complexity score of 1, 3, or 7 (where 1 is easy and 7 is very complex) on long ago scrum project to address this problem. The engineers had to assign the complexity together before choosing tasks. It worked _ok_, probably better than where you are now. It can be hard to judge the complexity up front but it at least gives everyone a little insight into what is taking so long. You might be able to explain the problem and suggest a solution to your project manager, they might find it useful as well. I believe it is similar to "Story Points".

Comment: @Flater I agree, my question was indeed the unfair distribution of tasks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer your direct question: no, this would not be "agile friendly". Forcing a distribution of tasks to developers to meet a goal which is not *delivering value to the customer* is almost the antithesis of Agile.

However, what you're seeing here is just a symptom of the bigger problem: neither your company nor your client is actually engaging in an agile process - they're doing what many, many other companies do: hiring a "scrum master", putting in a few trappings of a scrum process (daily standup, scrum ceremonies) and calling it "Agile" *without actually making any real changes to the process*.

The trouble is you almost certainly can't do anything about this; if your "scrum master" is using number of tasks completed as a metric, they are incompetent, and arguing with incompetent people is generally a waste of time. Feel free to change your process however you like, and even call it "agile" to your client if you want, but don't pretend that it's actually agile unless it delivers value to the customer.

Comment: Processes like this are sometimes called "ScrumBut", meaning "we say we are doing Scrum, **but** actually we are not doing A, B, E, G, and H which are required by Scrum and we are only doing C and D sometimes, and we have modified F to be the opposite of what it actually means …"

Comment: /Completely/ agree with your second paragraph - hiring a "Scrum Master", "doing" the trappings of Agile, but changing nothing and improving even less.  It happens all too often.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You're missing the final point which is "then blaming Scrum for not working and going back to waterfall"...

Answer (score -1):

No, distributing the tasks is not agile.

1. Sprint tasks (items) are aimed on reaching the Sprint goal. And goal is the main focus of the Sprint. Everyone should be aimed not to take the most simple item, but the item which helps reaching the goal at specific moment. To make sure this is happening, you should spend a bit more time during Sprint Planning to agree on the sequence of steps you will follow during your planned Sprint to make sure to be focusing on Sprint goal. More than that, it is a frequent case when you need to add more items to the Sprint to help reaching the goal.
2. If the developers of your team try to take simple things and leave hard things to other team members, this means your team is not living the values of courage, respect, focus and commitment. I would also assume there are severe issues with openness as when the team is open about problems they have, things like someone taking all the simple job are solved pretty quickly.
3. Team is accountable as a whole. No team members can "shine" if Sprint goal is not reached. And if Sprint goal is reached, it's the whole team which "shines".

Do you have Retrospective meetings as the conclusion of every Sprint? Have you raised this issues with the team? What does your team think about this?

I would like to highlight: Scrum is not about daily "standups" and "sprints".